# Error while try to publish API WSO2 2.6.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I faced with following exception in wso2 api manager 2.6.0, when changing api lifecycle state to Publish.

> TID: [-1234] [] [2021-10-06 15:24:44,413] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle} -  org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element \n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [88,0]"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}} {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle}
> TID: [-1234] [] [2021-10-06 15:24:44,479] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl} -  Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed. Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element \n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [88,0]"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}} {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl}
> org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element \n at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [88,0]"},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
> at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:482)
> at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:344)
> at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
> at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
> at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2607)
> at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
> at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
> at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
> at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody198(APIProviderImpl.java:4321)
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:4249)
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus_aroundBody70(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:310)
> at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:306)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_14(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:50)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
> at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
> at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
> at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
> at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:498)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:114)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
> at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
> at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
> at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
> at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Are you having a distributed setup (separate gateways)? A similar issue has been reported in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9702

Comment: Can you check whether the content within the `<Environments>` tag within the `<APIGateway>` tag of the `api-manager.xml` is in the proper format? Seems like an issue with the format.

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah it's note a distributed setup.

Comment: @HisanHunais <APIGateway> and <Environments> https://pastebin.com/ECu2UtGW

Comment: Is this observed for all the APIs in your environment when trying to change or update the Lifecycle? or is it only observed with a specific API?

Comment: @Athiththan at this point I´ve observed the problem for all APIs.

Comment: These APIs were created using any WSO2 REST APIs? or from the Publisher portal itself?

Comment: @Athiththan Created from the Publisher portal.

Comment: Can you try updating the hostname (localhost) in the `ServerURL` under the `Environments` section in `api-manager.xml` with your `local-ip-address` (which you have used to configure the `GatewayEndpoint`)? Do a restart after the change and try out the scenario. The mentioned error format basically occurs, when the API misses some meta while creating it using the REST APIs or when having connection breaks while publishing. Since you have created the APIs from the Portal, the suspect point is to check the connectivity of the ServerURL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a open tag at <APIM_HOME>/repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml

```
       </handlers>
    /api>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).